# How to respond to a POST request using HTML

Tags: jquery, html, httprequest

I am new to making HTTP requests and responses, the question might seem novice, but I want to know how can I write an HTML file that responds to Post request sent to it basically, if I am posting (name: "Donald Duck") how can I make the response something like "Hello Donald Duck"? Any help would be great, thank you!

I tried to google, but most commonly came across solutions using PhP, is there a way it can be done using HTML? I have used this site as reference https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
        <head>
          <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
          </script>
          <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
             $("button").click(function(){
               $.post("demo_test_post.asp",
              {
                name: "Donald Duck",
                city: "Duckburg"
              },
              function(data,status){
                alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
              });
            });
          });
          </script>
         </head>
         <body>
           <button>Send an HTTP POST request to a page and get the result 
           back</button>
         </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: You need create an API from .net or Java or PHP

Answer (score -4):

You can't. HTML is not a programming language.

HTTP requests are sent to HTTP servers which respond with an HTTP response. This response can be determined by the server mapping the URL onto a static file (but responding with a static file to a POST request defeats the object of using POST), by code internal to the server generating a custom response, or by the server invoking another program to determine what the response is.

HTTP servers and external programs invoked by them can be written in any programming language.

Comment: meaning I will have to use PhP?

Comment: PHP. Yes. It's what runs on the backend

Comment: @aishwaryajain — No. You can use any programming language.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on some options and how can they be used, it would be a great help, thank you!

Comment: Elaborate in what way?